# Как открыть доступ к локальному серверу на apache tomcat(java), через роутер извне?

Tags: java, apache, сервер, intellij-idea, tomcat

Суть в чем сегодня нужно сдать проект, back-end на java запускается у меня на локальном (apache tomcat через idea) сервере и доступен из браузера следующим образом localhost:8090.

Собственно стоит сказать что все это дело на ноутбуке и подключение происходит через роутер(и только так, потому что по другому, даже на время не могу сделать) роутер(собтсвенно мой) TPLINK MR3420.

Что я попытался сделать:
1) открыл порт 8090 на роутере
2) Поставил своему пк в сети постоянный адрес(192.168.0.23)(если правильно понял к своему мак адресу для моего роутера)
3) Добавил виртуальный сервер 
[image]

**Белого IP нет:**
Также завел аккаунт на noip, и доменное имя foodstories.hopto.org и поставил себе на комп соответствующую утилиту (DUC).

И настроил:

[image]

Собственно при заходе на адрес foodstories.hopto.org:8090/login кончено же ничего не сработало. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как настроить доступ к локальному серверу извне и настроить.

Comment: Если у вас нет белого `ip`, то через `Dynamic DNS` у вас не получится. Вам надо настроить `VPN` на каком-нибудь сервере с белым `ip`. А вот знаете, как работают штуки типо `skype`? Один и другой пк с серым `ip` подключаются к серверам скайп, на сетевом оборудовании создается временное правило, а потом сервера скайп просто передают адрес одного компьютера другому. Те быстренько соединяются, пока правила на роутерах не исчезли, и вуаля - два пк с серыми `ip` связаны. [Hole Punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)) называется. Правда, это тоже мало чем вам поможет...

Answer (score 1):

Динамический DNS обещает лишь разрешение вашего доменного адреса в ваш ip. Но! Если ваш провайдер в свою очередь не открыл порт(ы) на вашу машину - ничего не выйдет. Разрешаться будет ip провайдера.
Dynamic DNS полезен в том случае, если вы при подключении к интернету получаете белый (доступный по всем портам снаружи) но динамический ip, и бесполезен если вы за NAT провайдера (т.н. серый ip).

**Позвонил провайдеру**, действительно за NAT, попросил отключить, в **итоге все работает.**